# gulp-protractor e2e task fails to run

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, gulp, aurelia, gulp-protractor

#### Update: Seems like this is a bug in gulp-protractor. On their github page they filed it as a bug and will take a look into it. Source: https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor/issues/64

Only possible workaround you can do until the bug is resolved is change the directory of your project to something that doesn't include spaces.

---

So I'm trying to get an Aurelia project started including front end unit testing. Here is where the problem starts. When I try to run the e2e gulp task I get the following error:

> [10:45:44] using gulpfile ~\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectX\ProjectX\gulpfile.js 
>   [10:45:44] Starting 'build-e2e'...
>   [10:45:44] Finished 'build-e2e' after 207 ms
>   [10:45:44] Starting 'e2e'...
>   **'C:\Users\jorisd\Documents\Visual' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**
>   C:\Users\jorisd\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ProjectX\ProjectX\build\tasks\e2e.js:34
>       .on('error', function(e) {throw e; });
>   Error: protractor exited with code 1

Basically it's the highlighted code that has the problem. Since my path includes a space, it'll stop there for some reason.

Here's how my e2e.js file looks like right now:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var paths = require('../paths');
var to5 = require('gulp-babel');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var webdriverUpdate = require('gulp-protractor').webdriver_update;
var webdriverStandalone = require("gulp-protractor").webdriver_standalone;
var protractor = require('gulp-protractor').protractor;

// for full documentation of gulp-protractor,
// please check https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor
gulp.task('webdriver-update', webdriverUpdate);
gulp.task('webdriver-standalone', ['webdriver-update'], webdriverStandalone);

// transpiles files in
// /test/e2e/src/ from es6 to es5
// then copies them to test/e2e/dist/
gulp.task('build-e2e', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.e2eSpecsSrc)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(to5())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.e2eSpecsDist));
});

// runs build-e2e task
// then runs end to end tasks
// using Protractor: http://angular.github.io/protractor/
gulp.task('e2e', ['build-e2e'], function(cb) {
  return gulp.src(paths.e2eSpecsDist + '/*.js')
    .pipe(protractor({
      configFile: '/protractor.conf.js',
      args: ['--baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:9000']
    }))
    .on('end', function() { process.exit(); })
    .on('error', function(e) { throw e; });
});
```

The problem is situating in the e2e task with the configFile option. 
I tried change the line into the following:

```
configFIle: __dirname + '/protractor.conf.js',
```

But this aswell without result. If any of you know a workaround for including spaces in the configFile path, I'll be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

For me its working fine.

```
var angularProtractor = require('gulp-angular-protractor');

gulp.task('test', function (callback) {

 gulp
     .src([__dirname+'/public/apps/adminapp/**/test/**_test.js'])
     .pipe(angularProtractor({
         'configFile': 'public/apps/adminapp/app.test.config.js',
         'debug': false,
         'args': ['--suite', 'adminapp'],
         'autoStartStopServer': true
     }))
     .on('error', function(e) {
         console.log(e);
     })
    .on('end',callback);
```

});